# If $f$ is entire and $|f(z)|<|Ae^z|$, then show that $f(z)=Be^z$ for some $A,B\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

If someone can give a hint, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider $f(z)e^{-z}$. What does the estimate say about that function?

Comment: This inequality is equivalent to $|f(z)e^{-z}| < |A|.$

Comment: This is actually an application of [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(complex_analysis)).

Answer (score 7):

The function $f(z)e^{-z}$ is a bounded entire function and thus is constant by Liouville's theorem. Thus $f(z)e^{-z} = B$ for some constant $B$ and so $f(z) = Be^z$.